# Not getting response from tornado server while testing with infinite loop

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

Not getting response from tornado server while testing with infinite loop

Client :

```
from ws4py.client.tornadoclient import TornadoWebSocketClient
from tornado import ioloop
import random
import time
import itertools    
class MyClient(TornadoWebSocketClient):
     def opened(self):
         #for i in range(0,100000):
         #for i in itertools.count():
         while 1:
             test=random.choice('0123456789')
             self.send(test)
             time.sleep(2)

     def received_message(self, m):
         print(m)
         if len(m) == 175:
             self.close(reason='Bye bye')

     def closed(self, code, reason=None):
         ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

ws = MyClient('ws://localhost:9001', protocols=['http-only', 'chat'])
ws.connect()

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This is the server code using tornado server. I am able to get the response from server when using finite loop but not getting any response on my client when I test it with infinite loop.

Server :

```
# !/usr/bin/python
# import the libraries
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import os

# This is our WebSocketHandler - it handles the messages
# from the tornado server
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    # the client connected
    def open(self):
        print("New cient connected to server")
    # self.write_message("You are connected to server")

    # the client sent the message
    def on_message(self, message):
        # self.write_message(" from server ")
        self.write_message(message + "  received on server ")       

    # client disconnected
    def on_close(self):
        print("Client disconnected")

# start a new WebSocket Application
# use "/" as the root, and the
# WebSocketHandler as our handler
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", WebSocketHandler),
])

# start the tornado server on port 8888
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(9001)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Never call `sleep` from a Tornado application; it blocks the main thread and prevents any work from proceeding. Instead you want something like:

```
class MyClient(TornadoWebSocketClient):
    periodic_callback = None

    def opened(self):
        # period is in milliseconds.
        self.periodic_callback = ioloop.PeriodicCallback(self.send_random,
                                                         2000)

    def send_random(self):
        test = random.choice('0123456789')
        self.send(test)

    def closed(self, code, reason=None):
        self.periodic_callback.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your code but still not getting any response from server.I am able to get response using for loop up to 100000.I don't understand what's wrong with infinite loop.

Comment: Though on server side I am getting the notification of connection with client.